# VSCode prettier's printWidth

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm trying to set different width of row for my VSCode prettier[(extension)](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode) settings, but without any luck.
Tried different variations with prefixes or without in ~root/.vscode/settings.json:

```
"max-len": 120,
"printWidth": 120
"editor.max-len": 120,
"editor.printWidth": 120
"prettier.max-len": 120,
"prettier.printWidth": 120
```

none of it respect rules.

How can I solve it?

Comment: If you are using `prettier` I recommend use the `.pretierrc` file.

Comment: It is extension of VSCode, so all settings of extensions need to be in VSCode settings

Comment: I use VSCode and the extension reads the `.pretierrc` file as well. Check [the documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode#user-content-settings)

Comment: .prettierrc has precedence over VSCode settings. But even setting "prettier.printWidth": 120 in .prettierrc, it still divides a line much smaller than 120 chars. The same code is not divided by Prettier when the same line is made smaller reducing a string for example. Think this may be a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Find `.editorconfig` file in your project. If exists, add `max_line_length = 120` to it.

See "Print Width" in Prettier document https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html for details

Comment: this worked for me where setting vscode settings did nothing. The project already had a .editorconfig file, but max_line_length was not set in it.

Answer (score 2):

- Did you consider the file extensions Prettier is actually [supporting](https://prettier.io/docs/en/index.html)?
- If yes, when you have the file opened, is "Prettier" selected in the status bar on the bottom right?
- If yes, open the "Output" tab in VS Code and try to format the file. What do you see as output (you might need to select "Prettier" in the dropdown of the "Output" tab).

Comment: Rechecking the supported file extensions made me realize my issue. Many places show examples of using prettier with nextjs setup, but prettier by default does not support .tsx files, only .jsx. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731587/prettier-doesnt-format-tsx-file

Answer (score 1):

I had to restart VS Code after changing the `printWidth` value in `.prettierrc.js`, in order for the plugin to pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open vscode
2. ctrl + ,
3. find Prettier: Print Width (you can use search)
4. by default 80 - usually set 120

Answer (score -1):

You're missing trailing commas on line 2 and 4. Click on the "Prettier" link in the status bar and it will tell what to debug.