# vscode prettier doesn't format .tsx file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier, tsx

I've used the Prettier extension in the Visual Studio code editor for a long time, but recently, I have been writing to React with Typescript. So I need to configure for Prettier to format `.tsx` files.

Comment: Do you have `prettier` as a dependency of this project?

Comment: I just had to restart the VS Code.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

***Update 2024***

Create a `.vscode` folder at the root of your project. In the `.vscode` folder, create the `settings.json` file, and in it, write this section:

```
{
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "[typescriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `.vscode` in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: This works; however, how can we apply this to all projects? Do we have to create a `.vscode` folder with a `settings.json` file every time?

Comment: @AnthonyAvila
You can modify VSCode settings globally by pressing `Ctrl +, `
 then search the typescript

Comment: this worked but this seem to be the default behaviour with formatOnSave flag, I have to set typescript formatter as prettier to get the desired behaviour

Answer (score 224):

Edit setting with following in `settings.json` of VScode

```
"[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

Comment: In case you are wondering how to access settings.json -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909052/5888998

Comment: To open settings follow these steps:

Shift + CMD + P,
Type "settings",
Click on "preferences: open settings(JSON)"

Comment: This worked - thank you - but I don't understand why I had to specifically add the block for `typescriptreact` when I already had `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"` set at both a global and workspace level.

Comment: You can also choose `Open User Settings (JSON)`

Answer (score 81):

Expanding on [iNeelPatel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10181989/ineelpatel)'s answer, I had to add two lines to VSCode JSON settings:

```
"[typescript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" },
"[typescriptreact]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" }
```

Comment: worked for me 

Comment: This is the best and most useful answer! for this question

Comment: for me vscode prettier doesn't format .ts file, so "[typescript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" } helps... thanks

Answer (score 15):

An easy UI alternative to what has been proposed already:

1. Search for "default formatter" in your vscode settings.
2. Click on "Text Editor" and set the default formatter to "Prettier - Code formatter".
3. Enjoy.

Comment: For some reason this was working for me for .js files only. But then after I also deactivated `TypeScript > Format: Enable` it started working for my .tsx files as well.

Answer (score 5):

This will give perfect solution

"Same thing happened to me just now. I set prettier as the Default Formatter in Settings and it started working again. My Default Formatter was null."

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108447#issuecomment-706642248

Answer (score 3):

**My Usage**

The way I set this up is to use eslint's `.eslintrc.json` file. First of all, in the `"extends"` array, I've added

```
"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
```

and

```
"prettier/@typescript-eslint"
```

Then, I've set `"parser"` to `"prettier/@typescript-eslint"`

Finally, in `"plugins"` array I've added `"@typescript-eslint"`.

You'll need to grab a couple of NPM packages (install with the `-D` option):

```
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
@typescript-eslint/parser
```

---

For reference, my entire `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "project": "./src/tsconfig.json",
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "jest"],
  "rules": {
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

On my side simply adding the two lines in the config file didn't work but deactivating the `Typescript > Format: Enable` option in settings worked.

Comment: This fixed this issue for me! Not sure why, as it's counterintuitive. I'm using the VSCode prettier extension and have my User [Javascript] Default Formatter pointing to that (Prettier). That was working for .js files. But it was not working for .tsx files - until I deactived `TypeScript > Format: Enable`.

Answer (score 1):

After setting Prettier as the default formatter in Vs-code and checking 'format on save' it still was not working for me. What finally did it was deleting and then recreating my project's `.prettierrc` file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
"[javascriptreact,typescript,typescriptreact]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps helpful to someone - if with all the above, still no luck, you may want to restart VSCode or from command palette (`⌘CMD + ⇧Shift + P`) and fire up "Restart ESLint Server" - that shd do, then :)